# Tips for interactive machine vision grid

Tags: python, image, qt, user-interface

I am working on a program for machine vision. I am trying to do the following:

1. Grab image at a certain zoom level and find borders.
2. Take that image and subdivide into a fixed sized grid (which is pre-determined).
3. Project the image+grid in a UI and allow a user to select/deselect individual grid boxes.

Currently I am using PyQt+Python2.7 with C++ for the computations. I am just wondering if there is a good tutorial for the UI grid section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Graphics View Framework](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html). Add each grid item as a separate pixmap using `scene->addPixmap`. Make items selectable using `item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);`. Use scene's `selectionChanged` signal and `scene->selectedItems()` to know about selected items.

You can use `QPixmap::copy` to cut off a rectangle.